# Compatibility problems with using getResource() together with URL

Tags: java, linux

I need to get a resource from within a jar file using `getClass().getResource()`. The problem is that I have a URL as input and there seems to be some compatibility issues between URL and getResource()

So what I do currently is,

```
getClass().getResource(url.getPath());
```

This does however not work (and neither does getResourceAsStream()) since the output from `url.getPath()` looks something like this,

```
file:/mavenPath/repository/myJar.jar!/path/to/resource/myResource.ext
```

However the path

```
/path/to/resource/myResource.ext
```

would work. I also noted that

```
url.toURI()
```

works but,

```
url.toURI().getPath()
```

returns null (I am not sure if this is related). So the problem seems to be this first path,

```
file:/mavenPath/repository/myJar.jar!
```

Which causes problems with the classloader.

Does anyone have a solution to this? I doubt I am to be the first one with the problem so there should be some solution I hope. The problem is that this notation probably differs from Windows to Linux I am afraid to cause compatibility between windows and linux if I manually modify the path.

It might be worth noting that I use Linux and the resources is included in the classpath, but not inside the same jar file as the method where I have problems.

**EDIT**

Someone pointed out that getResource() returns a URL. The problem is that I have multiple URLs with dependencies (actually they are MIBs). The function reading the URLs is located in another library and takes a String input. It also includes some IANA and IETF standard MIBs.

Comment: I don't get it: getResource() returns a URL, why would you use it if you already have an URL?

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes agreed! The URLs have some complicated sorting since there are dependencies between the resources. The function which reads the resources and sorts them takes a string input. The reason for this is that it is allowed to add resources as strings as well in this function. This is not my choice, but I have to comply with it. Also, I prefer to not rewrite another library just to make my implmentation work.